# RewriteEngine to rewrite one of multiple variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Can someone help with a RewriteRule for the .htaccess file?

I an searching and trying out since hours :(

I need to rewrite this:

index.php?page=Thread&threadID=34549

to:

index.php/Thread/34549

The Numer should be preserved.

It should be simple, but i simply cant find out how.

Comment: Have you tried turning it (server) off and on again? <After editing your htaccess files>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([0-9]+)/? index.php?page=$1&threadID=$2 [L,QSA]
```